# Cross Domain javascript call using porthole not working in firefox

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website(**abc.com**) in which a iframe(**efg.com**) is opened in a facebox.i have used porthole to do a java-script cross domain scripting, but this is working fine in chrome but not in firefox and internet explorer.

is there any other way to send a message in a cross domain environment using javascript?

Comment: JSONP is one way this can be accomplished :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache url rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same issues using porthole, I can't send message event from child iframe to the parent page on firefox and IE, the problem is that my iframe code doesnt have a name attribute only id, so I added a name attribute to my iframe and viola! it now works on firefox and IE now!.

Please make sure your iframe will have a name and ID.  :)